# Find smallest integer that satisfy a system

Tags: equation-solving

```
f[m_,n_]:=-205 m^2-(672m)n+324(n^2)
```

I want to find the smallest positive integer M such that all of the numbers f(m,n), for m=1,2,...,M and n=1,2,...,M are distinct.

Comment: The smallest or the largest?

Comment: `(Unequal @@ Flatten@Table[f[m, n], {n, 0, #}, {m, 0, #}]) & /@ {19, 
  20}`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Also ... try to learn how to upvote, accept, etc. See the long comment above.

Comment: Sorry, and smallest

Comment: The smallest is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on [belisarius's example code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79553/find-smallest-integer-that-satisfy-a-system#comment215726_79553):

```
NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, ! (Unequal @@ Flatten@Table[f[m, n], {n, 0, #}, {m, 0, #}]) &]
(* 1 *)
```

This increments $M$ until your condition is satisfied, which it is trivially for $M=1$.  Removing the `!` gives us the first $M$ such that there is a repeated value of $f$ ($M=20$).

Answer (score 1):

Just a variant of 2012rcampion, producing the largest integer that fulfils condition:

```
NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, 
  Length@Union[f @@@ Tuples[Range[#], 2]] == #^2 &] - 1
```